# Image Management Page for Users

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I want to create a 'photo_management' page for any user that is logged in to my site, where they can:

- Upload photos to their account
- See all photos that have been uploaded
- Delete photos from their account

Ideally:

- The photos are displayed as a simple gallery, rather than as a file structure
- Upload function can select and process multiple images at once
- Each image that is uploaded and therefore displayed can be selected (with a tick box), and a delete button will delete whichever images are selected.
- Everything is displayed on one page

Is there a package that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [**flask-cloudy**](https://github.com/mardix/flask-cloudy)([GitHub](https://github.com/mardix/flask-cloudy), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cloudy/)) and its local storage option. They have an example app which has most of the functionality you are looking for: **https://github.com/mardix/flask-cloudy/tree/master/example**.

Flask-Cloudy can do all of your first three requirements:

- Upload photos to their account
- See all photos that have been uploaded
- Delete photos from their account

But it does not have any account/login functionality. You will have to implement that yourself. I would recommend using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)([Docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [GitHub](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Login/)).